# Internet sharing + VPN?

Tags: windows-xp, vpn

I have a VPN between two Windows XP computers - the first one is connected to internet via local area connection and it's supposed to be the server, while the other one is the client. The VPN connection is being established succesfully, but the client cannot access the internet through the vpn server. My question: How to enable Internet Connection sharing so the VPN client could use it ? 
Important: There is no " Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection" in the advanced tab - it's a local area connection from which the computer is connected to the internet.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your setup is but vpn is not for internet sharing. You need to implement NAT if you want to use your server as proxy. Search for RRAS. Again i can't suggest much as not sure what your configuration is.